# Get subtotals in the xsl:for-each-group loop

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a XML structure similar to like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
    <businessobjects>
        <InventoryItem>
            <EntryDate>2022-04-28</EntryDate>
        </InventoryItem>
        <InventoryItem>
            <EntryDate>2022-05-02</EntryDate>
        </InventoryItem>
        <InventoryItem>
            <EntryDate>2022-05-28</EntryDate>
        </InventoryItem>
        <InventoryItem>
            <EntryDate>2022-06-28</EntryDate>
        </InventoryItem>
        <InventoryItem>
            <EntryDate>2022-05-16</EntryDate>
        </InventoryItem>
    </businessobjects>
</document>
```

with following stylesheet I easily can count the number of InventoryItems added for each month and a total of InventoryItems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="header"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="businessobjects">
        <xsl:variable name="items">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="InventoryItem" group-by="substring(EntryDate, 1, 7)">
                <MonthGroup>
                    <Month>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </Month>
                    <ItemCount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
                    </ItemCount>
                     <CumulativeItemCount><!-- How to calculate sum of InventoryItems of all previously processed groups --></CumulativeItemCount>
                </MonthGroup>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Summary>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$items"/>
            <total>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($items//ItemCount)"/>
            </total>
        </Summary>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What makes me headache: How I can calculate subtotals for each group summing up all Items of previuosly processed groups. The resulting XML should look like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Summary xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <MonthGroup>
      <Month>2022-04</Month>
      <ItemCount>1</ItemCount>
      <CumulativeItemCount>1</CumulativeItemCount>
   </MonthGroup>
   <MonthGroup>
      <Month>2022-05</Month>
      <ItemCount>3</ItemCount>
      <CumulativeItemCount>4</CumulativeItemCount>
   </MonthGroup>
   <MonthGroup>
      <Month>2022-06</Month>
      <ItemCount>1</ItemCount>
      <CumulativeItemCount>5</CumulativeItemCount>
   </MonthGroup>
   <total>5</total>
</Summary>
```

Unsuccessfully tried to run a named template by xsl:call-template. But I was not able to find a condition to stop summing up Items at a certain point and I guess it is even not the correct appraoch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily process the elements you create in the variable `items`; as the current version of XSLT is 3.0 and all supported versions of e.g. Saxon or Altova do support that below I do it with an XSLT 3.0 accumulator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="header"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="businessobjects">
        <xsl:variable name="items">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="InventoryItem" group-by="substring(EntryDate, 1, 7)">
                <MonthGroup>
                    <Month>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </Month>
                    <ItemCount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
                    </ItemCount>
                     <CumulativeItemCount><!-- How to calculate sum of InventoryItems of all previously processed groups --></CumulativeItemCount>
                </MonthGroup>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Summary>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$items"/>
            <total>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($items//ItemCount)"/>
            </total>
        </Summary>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="cumulative-item-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="ItemCount" select="$value + xs:integer(.)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:template match="CumulativeItemCount" expand-text="yes">
      <xsl:copy>{accumulator-before('cumulative-item-count')}</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are really stuck with an XSLT 2.0 processor you can of course use some other processing than an accumulator.

Comment: Excellent, I wasn't aware that even xslt 3.0 was implemented in the processor

Comment: Anyway I didn't konw how easy to achieve :)